# android - Manually set ninepatch size

Tags: android, nine-patch

How can I manually set the size of the fixed parts of a NinePatch in Android?

I want to resize the not-stretchable parts

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html):

> The NinePatch class permits drawing a bitmap in nine sections. The four corners are unscaled; the four edges are scaled in one axis, and the middle is scaled in both axes.

The edges are not intended to be arbitrarily scaled. This is not what nine patches are designed to do.

Comment: I mean that I have an image like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/DrUII.png and I want the left part to be smaller than it is. 
I need to change the image? In what way?

Comment: you need to change the image

Comment: @vincenzoc unless you want some sort of dynamic behavior, otherwise you should modify the 9patch image when making the APK instead of trying to change it at runtime.